# Corresponding /dev/ttyUSB0 on Windows to read/write use case with python

Tags: python, linux, windows, serial-port, fingerprint

i had to create a python program to read fingerprint sensor that works well on linux, Now i want the same code to run i windows but there is a problem with port, how to manage or access usb devices in windows with python. in brief how do i update my code so that it works on windows(**f = PyFingerprint('/dev/ttyUSB0', 57600, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x00000000)**)

```
import time
from pyfingerprint.pyfingerprint import PyFingerprint
from func import registerNewPerson

def runEnroll():
    ## Enrolls new finger
    ##

    ## Tries to initialize the sensor
    try:
        f = PyFingerprint('/dev/ttyUSB0', 57600, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x00000000)

        if ( f.verifyPassword() == False ):
            raise ValueError('The given fingerprint sensor password is wrong!')

    except Exception as e:
        print("Le capteur D'empreunte n'a pas pu etre initialise!")
        print('Exception message: ' + str(e))
        exit(1)
```

Comment: Please just try the COMx associated with the fingerprint reader such as 'COM3' instead of '/dev/ttyUSB0'. [pySerial API](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html)

Comment: okay thx, i try